# How to read a textfile using C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text file. I want read that file. But In that if the line starts with 6 then i want read that file otherwise leave that line and go to next line. If the line starts with 6 then i want to read that line from position 6 to 15 and 45 to 62. I want to implement this code in C#.NET. How to write that code? Can anyone Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string fileName)
{
    string line;
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line;
}

ReadLines("yourfile.txt")
    .Where(l => l.StartsWith("6"))
    .Select(l => new {Part1 = l.SubString(6, 9), Part2 = l.SubString(45, 17)});
```

Comment: Yes, but one that may be difficult for the OP to understand.

Comment: Why not File.ReadAllLines instead of your ReadLines method?

Comment: I hope teachers that assign these problems google to see if they asked stackoverflow for the answer! That being said, I like your solution.

Comment: Semantically easy to understand because of its expressiveness however not necessarily so programmatically if unfamiliar with the concepts. Any teacher will will know this answer was lifted if the level of the course is lower. Unless it's a Continuing Education course in which you often get experienced people in other languages who pick up the taught language quickly.

Answer (score 2):

`using System.IO`

Use Microsoft's [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx). [Example here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) but use the [Read(..) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader_methods(v=VS.90).aspx) for characters, Peek(..) to look ahead, etc.

> StreamReader is designed for character
>   input in a particular encoding,
>   whereas the Stream class is designed
>   for byte input and output. Use
>   StreamReader for reading lines of
>   information from a standard text file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use System.IO.TextReader classes & string functions to read the file & check the contents of each line.

MSDN has a nice example in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) article using StreamReader in C#.